# How to transfer a file from a Mac application to an iOS viewer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

We would like to develop a feature similar to what exists in InDesign: when you create a "folio", you can preview it in an iOS "viewer" app, providing:

- the iOS device is connected to the Mac with a USB cable
- the "viewer" is opened on the iOS device.

The description of this feature is available at http://helpx.adobe.com/digital-publishing-suite/help/preview-folios-articles.html#use_preview_on_device.

There are 2 questions:

- how can InDesign detect that the "viewer" app is opened on the device?
- how can InDesign transfer a file to the iOS device, and have the "viewer" open the file?

We are aware that file transfer is possible using iTunes, but it's not the method used by InDesign (the way they do it is much more simple and straightforward).

Googling or searching on Stack Overflow does not seem to provide reliable answers so far.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a local web service inside your Mac app and then pulling it over Wi-Fi on the iOS app?

Comment: Yes, it's the way most our competitors do. But it's much less elegant than Adobe's method.

Comment: I'd argue that it's *more* elegant, in that a user isn't required to tether a cable to the computer. Protocols like Bonjour can ensure reliable connectivity too.

Answer (score 1):

Well, accessing iOS devices from USB is not authorized by Apple, so you got three possibilities :

- Use [MobileDevice](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/MobileDevice_Library) private framework from Apple, you can read files from your app using the Document folder of you app via AFC.
- Use [libmobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org), an open-source and cross-platform library, same as MobileDevice but not so stable across iOS versions.
- Use [usbmux](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Usbmux) tunnel to connect to your app via sockets (require MobileDevice or libimobiledevice)

I think that usbmux is the best solution, the protocol used in usb never changed a lot and is very stable, even in libimobiledevice.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for something authorized by Apple. Do you think Adobe has a special authorization from Apple?

Comment: No, Adobe just fine a way using usbmux I think.. Apple seems to accept usbmux communications. DeviceSync (https://itunes.apple.com/app/devicesync-for-ios/id737867459) use peertalk library (https://github.com/rsms/peertalk)

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure I understand. You start your answer by mentioning that "accessing iOS devices from USB is not authorized by Apple". In your comment, you mention that "Apple seems to accept usbmux communications". So, at the end of the day, is usbmux authorized or not?

Comment: As said in peertalk page it's not authorized but Apple accept some apps that use it. If you're planing to publish an app to the the AppStore you'll need some luck to get accepted. So the answer is no, it's not accepted by Apple.

Comment: Thanks again for the comment. So, you think Adobe was lucky?

Comment: Adobe use self signed apps that don't pass to Apple checks, with Enterprise developer account if I'm not wrong

Comment: You are wrong, sorry. The Adobe Viewer is available on the App Store, so it went through Apple checks.